# When functional equations determine a unique global analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm learning about analytic continuations and global analytic functions which were seen to be connected components of the sheaf of analytic germs.

Sometimes we get problem sets in which we are asked to define the largest branch possible of some function $f$, where $f$ satisfies some functional relationship. For example, $f^2(z) - z\sin(z) = 0$

Answers to such problem sets may tell us to "note that $f$ has a branch point at such and such location." Do statements like that even make sense? What if two different global analytic functions (two components of the sheaf) can satisfy this relation and have completely different branch points? Don't we have to know that a functional relation $G(z, f) = 0$ specifies a unique component in the sheaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if two different global analytic functions (two components of the sheaf) can satisfy this relation and have completely different branch points?

That could happen: the equation 
$$(f(z)^2-z)(f(z)-z)=0$$
is satisfied by a function with a branch point at $0$, and also by an entire function.

However, we may be able to say something branch points for *some* equations. Let's consider equations of the form $\Phi(f(z)) = \Psi(z)$. Suppose that  $\Psi'(z_0)\ne 0$ and $\Phi'$ vanishes at every point of the set $\{z: \Phi(z) = \Psi(z_0)\}$. Then $f$ cannot be holomorphic at $z_0$. This consideration applies, e.g., to  $f(z)^2=z$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that theorem? It seems like a version of the implicit function theorem.

Comment: @Mark It's the chain rule. If $f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$, then $\Psi'(z_0) = \Phi'(f(z_0)) f'(z_0)$. But we have zero on the right, and nonzero on the left.

Comment: Oh of course, thanks.

Comment: But maybe there is a uniqueness theorem for simple functional relations? Like maybe if the function can't be "factored"